# Change attribute [disable] value on button click within a row of a table- angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a table with the following attributes

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="usersdisplaytable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Object Name</th>
            <th>Read</th>
            <th>Write</th>
            <th>Update</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let items of accessLists; let i = index" [attr.id]="i">
            <td>
                {{items.Object_Name}}
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" [disabled]="disableread">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" [disabled]="disablewrite">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" [disabled]="disableupdate">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" [disabled]="disabledelete">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="UpdateAccess(items,$event)">
                    {{buttonName}}
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to enable and disable the checkbox of a particular row when I click the button.

[image]

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Comment: You can do the thing that Pardeep did (bind in to the data variable) or you can use an array of disables. Either will do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the same variable for `disableread` on the entire table especially with *ngFor. You'll end up disabling/enabling all the checkboxes.

The quickest fix here would be to create an array of your disables with the same length as your data.

```
class Component {
    disableread: boolean[] = [];
    data = ["hello","hi","aloha","sayonara"]
    constructor() {
        // lets assume disableread is initially false
        for(let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
            this.disableread[i] = false;
        }
    }

    UpdateUIToggle(index) {
        this.disableread[index] =  !this.disableread[index]
    }

}
```

And then on your html

```html
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let d of data; let i = index"> 
    <td>{{d}}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" [disabled]="disableread[i]"></td>
    <td>
     <button (click)="UpdateUIToggle(i)">Toggle</button>
    </td>

  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this can trick by just toggling your variable binding in your calling method like this -

```
UpdateAccess(item, event) {
    itme.disabledelete = !itme.disabledelete;
    // Your code
}

[disabled]="item?.disableread"
```